# How can I do Authorization Policies in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5.3, policies

I read here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#writing-policies

And I tried to like this

My FavoritePolicy is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Policies;
use App\User;
use App\Models\Favorite;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
class FavoritePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    public function view(User $user, Favorite $favorite)
    {
        return $user->id === $favorite->user_id;
    }
}
```

My FavoriteController is like this :

```
<?php
use App\Models\Favorite;
...
class FavoriteController extends ApiController
{
    ...
    public function index(Favorite $favorite)
    {
        $this->authorize('view', $favorite);
        return view('profile.favorite');
    }
}
```

My AuthServiceProvider is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use App\Models\Favorite;
use App\Policies\FavoritePolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Favorite::class => FavoritePolicy::class,
    ];
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

When I run my system to display favorite listing, there exist error like this :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 HttpException in Handler.php line 115: This action is
>   unauthorized.

What the implementation of Authorization Policies is correct?

I try `dd($user)` in view method(FavoritePolicy), the result displays user data is being logged. It's true

But I try `dd($favorite)`, the result does not display favorite data of the user who is currently logged. Whereas I check on the table, favorite data of the user who is currently logged is exist

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

There result of `dd($favorite)` :

```
Favorite {#498 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the output of `dd($favorite)`?

Comment: Consider adding the output of that dd() to your question instead, it's quite unreadable in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the additional info in your update!

So, you want to show the detail page of one specific `Favorite` entity, but only if the user is the owner of this entity?

Firstly a minor "issue": usually in Laravel the controller method that shows details of a specific entity is called `show`, not `index`. `index` is the name for methods that show a list of entities (in your example: a list of favorites).

Regarding your problem:
Your policy checks if the currently logged in user can view an empty `$favorite` (see the `dd($favorite)` output in your post update). Which means, that `$favorite` is also not set in your `index` method.

I guess, you have a route defined similar to this:

```
Route::get('favorite/{id}', 'FavoriteController@index');
```

This means, that the value of `id` is injected into your `index` method as a parameter, but not a `Favorite` entity. To query for the `Favorite` entity is something you need to do in the method.

So, your method should more look like this:

```
public function index($favoriteId)
{
    $favorite = Favorite::findOrFail($favoriteId);
    $this->authorize('view', $favorite);
    return view('profile.favorite')->with('favorite', $favorite);
}
```

Hope that helps! If not, please add a comment!

Comment: Btw this is a dunky way. There should be a way we don't need to call in controllers.